# Are these PHP conditionals the same or does one have an advantage

Tags: php, variables, conditional-statements

Is there any advantage to writing a PHP conditional like this:

```
if ($variable != NULL) {
```

versus

```
if (!empty($variable)) {
```

versus

```
if ($variable) {
```

Aren't they all same thing? It seems like the last is always the simplest if you are just trying to tell whether the variable exists or not. Thanks for helping me understand the difference here. I missed the first day of PHP 101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Sean but I'll outline what each does in plain English:

```
if ($variable != NULL) {
```

`$variable` will be `NULL` if it hasn't been set. This is practically the same as `isset` and the same as the variable being undefined.

```
if (!empty($variable)) {
```

Generally, this checks whether `$variable` as a string (`(string) $variable`) has a `strlen` of 0. However `true` will make it return `false`, as will integers that aren't 0 and empty arrays. For some reason (which I believe to be wrong) `$variable = '0';` will return `true`.

```
if ($variable) {
```

This true/false check acts like `(boolean) $variable` - basically whether the variable returns true when converted to a boolean.

One way to think about it is that it acts the same as empty, except returns the opposite value.

For more information on what I mean by `(boolean) $variable` (type casting/juggling) see this [manual page](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

(PHP devs: this is mainly by memory, if I'm wrong here please correct me!)

Comment: NULL isn't the same as undefined.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [this table](http://de3.php.net/types.comparisons) to get the skinny on PHP comparison operators.  There's a number of subtle differences between false, 0, "", NULL and variables that are simply undefined.

Answer (score 2):

When running in strict error mode (E_STRICT), the clauses

```
if ($variable) {}
```

and

```
if ($variable != null) {}
```

would throw Notices, when these variables are not initialized.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: variable
```

These notices are a indicators of flaws in the code, since the use of uninitialized is a possible security vulnerability. (Keyword: register_globals).

My favorite for checking the existence of a variable is

```
if (isset($variable)) {}
```

This checks, if the variable has been used before (read: initialized with a value != null).

Answer (score 1):

Related Question: [Weak typing in PHP: why use isset at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413929/weak-typing-in-php-why-use-isset-at-all)

Basically, they are not the same when dealing with empty values, null values, zero, and boolean values.