# php isset do you need it in a form check?

Tags: php, isset

I trying to understand if a isset is required during form processing when i check $_REQUEST["input_name"] if no value is passed it doesn't cry about it and php doesn't throw out an error if you are trying to access a array item which doesn't exist....i can use if($_REQUEST["input_name"])..
what about "empty" even in those cases i can use if()

THnks

Comment: If PHP isn't whinging about accessing things which don't exist, change its configuration so that it does - if you're not developing and testing with the most pedantic error level (E_ALL & E_STRICT), then you are going to write crappy, non-portable and possibly unsafe code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($_REQUEST["input_name"])
```

will throw a notice (error) if "input_name" doesn't exist, so isset() is recommended.

Comment: isset() does suppress the warning, but $_REQUEST is a sucky way to go about capturing form input in most cases.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't recommend using the `$_REQUEST` superglobal for capturing form input, unless you're testing a form. Use `$_GET` or `$_POST` instead, unless you have a really good reason.

Also, `isset()` and `array_key_exists()` both do the same trick with regard to array keys, although `array_key_exists()` is clearer in an arrays context.

I recommend using:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); //E_ALL - All errors and warnings
```

within your development environment, as that can expose where better practices might be applied, such failure to declare variables before they are used, etc.

Comment: Magic values aren't fun. You can just do `error_reporting(E_ALL);` - `E_ALL` is a valid constant.

Comment: Yea, E_ALL is clearer and also more reliable in case the constant is changed in the future (no pun intended).

Comment: Changed to the more fun E_ALL

Comment: I am using error_reporting(65535) just for sure that everything is switched on;) For example [E_STRICT is not included in E_ALL](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) (I don't understand the logic behind it).

Answer (score 5):

There are different type of error levels. Checking a variable that is not set only throws a notice. Your [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is probably set to ignore those. It is best practice to always use `isset` when you want to check if a variable has been set, although [it does have its gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413929/weak-typing-in-php-why-use-isset-at-all).

Doing only what you are doing above, for example, if `$_REQUEST["input_name"]` is the string "0", it will evaluate to false. Also it is not a good idea to use $_REQUEST to begin with, as it can be affected by stuff like cookies and such and it's usually a code smell for bad architecture.

Comment: +1; it's important to check whether or not the value is set, rather than inadvertently rely on PHP coercing the value into a boolean properly

Answer (score 4):

using $_REQUEST is pretty much a hack. You should be using $_POST or $_GET (depending on what you are doing) and you should use isset().

Every book I've read on PHP seems to say that.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, at least for testing, set error reporting to E_ALL (all errors and warnings) either in your php.ini or in code using error_reporting(E_ALL); ([Look into adding E_STRICT](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) too.) Better to get an obvious notice about an error up front, than to have something subtle go wrong that you don't catch till later.

Avoid using $_REQUEST, which is too vague (it includes GET, POST AND cookie values), and use the $_POST or $_GET if those are what you really mean, and do check with `isset($_POST["input_name"])`

The short answer is "Yes." :)