# Is there any reason to use isset()?

Tags: php, isset

Why should I use `if (isset($var)) {}` rather than just `if ($var) {}`?  It seems to do the same thing and just take extra processing.  Thanks!

Comment: What if `$var` is `false`, `0` or `''`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weak typing in PHP: why use isset at all?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413929/weak-typing-in-php-why-use-isset-at-all)

Comment: Don't worry about "extra processing".  Your application doesn't know the difference either way.  Shaving nanoseconds is pointless without measurement.

Comment: search before posting..!

Comment: I prefer not to close this question, as this could be a reference. :) What say guys?

Comment: I was under the understanding that 'false' would be the equivalent of 'if (!$var) {}' and was unaware this was considered poor form and resulted in an error, as I have encountered one.  Thank you for the information, everybody.  Additionally, I did search, and didn't find the answer...just not very well, apparently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Reason**

The reason is, `isset()` will return boolean and doesn't throw a warning when you check for the existence of variable and proceed. Also, there is a possibility that, a variable may have zero values:

1. `false`
2. `0`
3. `""`

But they will be already set.

---

**Example**

```
$varb = false;
$vari = 0;
$vars = "";

isset($varb) // true
isset($vari) // true
isset($vars) // true

if ($varb) // false
if ($vari) // false
if ($vars) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `isset()` to check if a variable has been declared.

The other method checks what value `$var` has. So if `$var` happened to contain `false` then the condition would be false but you wouldn't whether the variable wasn't set or the variable contained `false`.