# Must I use php isset to check variable?

Tags: php

I read this answer:
[Is there any reason to use isset()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286321/is-there-any-reason-to-use-isset)

I still have a question.
If I want to check some var from POST.
Can I use:

```
$foo="".$_POST["foo"];
```

instead of

```
if(isset($_POST["foo"])){
    $foo=$_POST["foo"];
else{
    $foo="";
}
```

This is any reason to immunize it.
Thanks

Comment: If `foo` is not set, you'll still get `Notice: Undefined index 'foo'`, so yes.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about another question. It should be a comment.

Comment: You can shorten it to `$foo = isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : '';`  with a ternary operator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any reason to use isset()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15286321/is-there-any-reason-to-use-isset)

Comment: Hi. I think that this a useful shortcut for me. The  "Is there any reason to use isset()?" is not duplicate, because the behavior of my code throw error, but work well, and the other question not work the same.
The answer: $foo = isset($_POST['foo']) ? $_POST['foo'] : ''; give a useful information also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Michael Berkowski wrote this in the comments as well!

If you're just looking to simplify the implementation, you could use an inline statement.

`$foo = (isset($_POST['foo'])) ? $_POST['foo'] : "";`

Without `isset` you won't know if the `$_POST['foo']` actually exists in the given context, so you'll typically get error messages thrown to your screen!

Comment: Or your log file, depending on the error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to use:

```
$foo="".$_POST["foo"];
```

Will cause a notice to be raised if $_POST["foo"] is not set. But if your error reporting is set to ignore notices, then whether you use isset() or not is irrelevant. If you don't want a notice to be raised, though, you'll have to use isset().

Answer (score 0):

I like:

```
$foo = ($foo) ? $foo : '';
```

Personally :)