# PHP: use isset in ternary or not?

Tags: php, isset

say i have this function:

```
function foo($var = null) {

     return $var ? 'good' : 'bad';
  // return (isset($var) && !empty($var)) ? 'good' : 'bad';
}
```

this function works as expected and it should be syntaticaly correct, as `$var` default value is always set , is there any reason to use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and `empty` PHP function?

P.S: 
`good` is acceptable when `$var` is not `null` `false` or `''`

Comment: use isset. it saved you if due to any reason $var is not set

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413929/weak-typing-in-php-why-use-isset-at-all

Comment: I use like this: `$page = (isset($_GET["page"])) ? $_GET["page"] : "index";`. This is good.

Comment: `$var` and `isset($var)` express different things if you look closely! So it depends on _what_ you want to test here...

Comment: Maybe it can prevent an `unset()` before the return statement? I don't think it's really needed...

Comment: Depends what you want. Please clarify when you want `good`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath your right. `good` is acceptable when `$var` is not `null` `false` or `''`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, with your `if` test, php procedes to a type inference.

So there are values in `$var` that will echo `bad` even if they're not null.

For a more precise answer, you should check [PHP type comparison tables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) : you have exemples of the differences between `if($x)`, `isset()`, `is_null()` and `empty()` depending on the value of the variable you test.

Comment: woow, php type comparison tables is excellent resource, i should save an snapshot of that on my desktop