# Modify submit button to recognize number of selections

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on a series of database-driven tests that display on mysite/test/$test-url. After a user selects their answers and clicks the submit button, they're forwarded to mysite/test/grade.php.

The script below captures the test page's URL, so that the proper answers can be displayed on grade.php.

```
<div id="quiz" rel="key" style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <form action="grade.php" method="post" id="quiz">
    <ol>
      <li style="display: none;">
<?php echo join ($Base, ''); ?>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="hidden" name="PreviousURL" value="<?php echo $MyURL; ?>" id="url" />
    <input type="hidden" name="user_token" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['user_token']) ? $_POST['user_token'] : '' ; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Quiz" />
  </form>
</div>
```

If someone visits grade.php without first visiting a test page, all they see is a pretty much blank page. However, a person who visits a test page and clicks the submit button without answering any questions will be forwarded to the answers page, which will display the answers. In other words, it makes it easy to cheat.

So here's my question: How can I modify my script so that the answers aren't displayed on grade.php unless a user selects an answer to every question? An alternative would be modify it so that a user isn't forwarded to grade.php in the first place unless they've selected all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do a loop trough all the answers, if one is empty you dont show anything.

Imagine you have 3 questions;

```
$_POST['Question1']
$_POST['Question2']
$_POST['Question3']
```

Well if you do this :

```
if(!$_POST['Question1'] || !$_POST['Question2'] || !$_POST['Question3']){

   // SHOW NOTHING
}
else{
   // SHOW WHAT YOU WANT.
}
```

Now if you want to do it in JQUERY. You can prevent the form to load to your php by checking before if all the answer have been given.

same here, you use https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ and then you go trough each answer of your array, for example :

```
$('#myform').submit(function(event){
  var answers = $('#myform').serializeArray();
  $.each(answers , function(index,value){
     if(value == ''){
       event.preventDefault();
       alert('you did not answer all the questions');
     }

   });
}
```

Comment: Even if you do it with JS you should do the check in PHP as well. If a websavvy user reads the page's source code, they can redirect themselves without worrying about your pesky JS checks.

Comment: Good tip. These aren't really "critical" tests required for resumes, etc.; if a person wants to cheat, they're only cheating themselves. Still, it would be nice to make it as solid as possible.

Answer (score 0):

check you $_POST if it has the values that you ask in your test (and they aren't empty). If so, than you could show smth like "please answer tests before" or you redirect via header function to your test.php.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. If a user answers no questions at all, $_POST should be empty, right? So if they answer at least one question, it should have a value. But how can I modify it so they have to answer ALL the questions? Most of my tests will have either 10 or 25 questions. Is there a way I could simply count the answers to determine if they answered every question?

Comment: I wouldn't do smth like  
    "if(!$_POST['Question1'] || !$_POST['Question2'] || !$_POST['Question3']){  "
rather do:  
"!isset($_POST['Question1'], $_POST['Question2'] , $_POST['Question3'])  "
or check all with !empty() (!empty($_POST['Question1']) ...)

Comment: Why is it better ? I'm interested because i always use !$myvariable

Comment: because http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413929/weak-typing-in-php-why-use-isset-at-all. check out the answer of sirlancelot

Comment: I forgot to add: what is not in that link: if you check with ! on a variable that was not created yet, php throws a notice (e.g.: "PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: a in - on line 2") which is also not good